# Thread safe pattern for multiple properties

Tags: .net, multithreading, properties, thread-safety

I have an object that has about 15 properties of either String, decimal?, DateTime? or int?.
I have a collection of of this class that is manipulated from multiple threads. I would like to make sure that the values of the objects' properties are accessed (read/written) in a thread safe manner,  while writing the least amount of code.
Is there such a way instead of using private backers and doing explicit lock in the getter and setter of every single property?
Here is what I have to do now for each property:

```
public class ManyProperties
{
    private Object mLock = new Object;
    private string _personName;
    public string PersonName {
        get {            
             lock (mLock){
                 return _personName;
             }           
        }
        set { 
             lock (mLock){
                  _personName = value; 
             }
        }
    }

    private string _beginAmount;
    public decimal? BeginAmount {
        get {            
             lock (mLock){
                 return _beginAmount;
             }           
        }
        set { 
             lock (mLock){
                  _beginAmount = value; 
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx and edit your question to be clearer about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: For better performance you can use ReaderWriterLockSlim and different lock objects for each property

Answer (score 4):

Properties do not usually work in isolation. Having each property thread-safe doesn't help if you can't get a correct and valid *pair* etc of values. A more appropriate approach is to make the entire thing immutable, and let the caller get a **snapshot**:

```
public class ManyProperties
{
    private readonly string _personName;
    public string PersonName { get { return _personName; } }

    private readonly decimal? _beginAmount;
    public decimal? BeginAmount { get { return _beginAmount; } }

    public ManyProperties(string personName, string decimal? beginAmount) {
       _personName = personName;
       _beginAmount = beginAmount;
    }
}
```

then:

```
var snapshot = whatever.Properties;
var name = snapshot.PersonName;
...
var amount = snapshot.BeginAmount;
```

These will now **always be consistent**. Plus there are zero locks. Reading / updating a reference is always atomic, too - so no torn values.

The important thing is not to do:

```
var name = whatever.Properties.PersonName;
...
var amount = whatever.Properties.BeginAmount;
```

because here there is no longer any guarantee that `name` and `amount` came from the same `ManyProperties` instance: someone could have swapped the reference between the two fetches.